How to resolve TypeScript type mismatch when using Fastify plugin in a Turbo monorepo
I'm building a Fastify plugin as a separate package in a Turbo monorepo using TypeScript and Tsup for bundling. The plugin works at runtime, but TypeScript throws a type mismatch error when trying to register the plugin in my Fastify app.
This is my package.json for the plugin:
{
  "name": "@dekada/redis-plugin",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A plugin for adding Redis client to Fastify",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup",
    "dev": "tsup --watch --onSuccess \"node --env-file=.env.development dist/index.js\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dekada/redis": "workspace:*",
    "fastify": "^5.0.0",
    "fastify-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "ioredis": "^5.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@dekada/typescript": "workspace:*",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.5",
    "tsup": "^8.3.0"
  }
}

My TypeScript Code for the Redis Plugin:
import type { FastifyInstance, FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify';
import { initializeRedis } from '@dekada/redis';
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';

interface RedisPluginOptions {
  host: string;
  port: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

export const redisPlugin: FastifyPluginAsync<RedisPluginOptions> = async function (
  server: FastifyInstance,
  options: RedisPluginOptions
) {
  const redis = initializeRedis({
    host: options.host,
    port: options.port,
    username: options.username,
    password: options.password,
  });

  server.decorate('redis', redis);

  server.addHook('onReady', async () => {
    try {
      await redis.connect();
      server.log.info('Connected to Redis');
    } catch (error) {
      server.log.error(error);
    }
  });
};

export default fp(redisPlugin, { name: 'redisPlugin' });

When I try to register the plugin in my Fastify app, I get the following TypeScript error:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(plugin: FastifyPluginCallback<{ host: string; port: number; username: string; password: string; }, RawServerDefault, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger>, opts?: FastifyRegisterOptions<...> | undefined): FastifyInstance<...> & ... 1 more ... & { ...; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof import("/path/to/project/libs/plugins/redis-plugin/dist/index")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FastifyPluginCallback<{ host: string; port: number; username: string; password: string; }, RawServerDefault, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger>'.

That's how i register it:
import type { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify'
import redisPlugin from '@dekada/redis-plugin'
import fastifyCookie from '@fastify/cookie'
import fastifyCsrf from '@fastify/csrf-protection'
import fastifyHelmet from '@fastify/helmet'
import fastifySession from '@fastify/session'
import Fastify from 'fastify'
import { csrfOptions, helmetOptions, serverOptions, sessionOptions } from './configs'
import authRoutes from './routes'

async function buildServer(): Promise<FastifyInstance> {
  const server = Fastify(serverOptions)

  // Plugins
  await server.register(fastifyHelmet, helmetOptions)
  await server.register(fastifyCookie)
  await server.register(fastifyCsrf, csrfOptions)
  await server.register(fastifySession, sessionOptions)
  await server.register(redisPlugin, { host: 'localhost', port: 6379, username: '', password: '' })

  // Routes
  await server.register(authRoutes, { prefix: 'api/auth' })

  return server
}

export default buildServer


That's my project-wide tsconfig:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2023",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2021"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./dist/.tsbuildinfo"
  }
}

And tsup config:
import { defineConfig } from 'tsup'

export default defineConfig(options => ({
  entryPoints: ['src/**/*.ts'],
  clean: true,
  format: ['cjs'],
  dts: true,
  ...options,
}))


Could it be that different versions of fastify or fastify-plugin are being used in your project?

both are latest
